# How to know the suffix of size in lvcreate

Tags: disk-usage, disk

I've to create a new volume group of 5G with lvcreate but the disk don't have enough space disk :

```
lvcreate -n lv_new -L5G   VGroup 
Volume group "VGroup" has insufficient free space (1279 extents): 1280 required.
```

How to modify the lvcreate command for extend of 1279. I don't know if I've to put a suffix like K for kilobyte or I've to apply the command without any suffix after the '-L' option

Comment: dubs it is a matter of available extents. What you can do is run ie: `lvcreate -n lv_new -L2G VGroup`  Then  `lvresize -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/VGroup-lw_new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just, instead of specifying the size using `-L`, tell `lvcreate` to use 100% of the free extents, or use a specified number of extents using `-l`; instead of `-L5G`, try `-l 1279` to use the remaining 1279 extents, or `-l 100%FREE` to use all remaining free extents (which seem to be 1279).